# MIPS assembly looping multiple .data

Tags: mips

I'm wondering how would I store a value like 0xaaaaaaaa in a loop throughout all four of my data words. I've been mostly comfortable with calling a single data and looping that, but now I'm dealing with 4 data words and have no idea how to put them into a loop.

Here's what I have for my code so far:

```
    .text
main:   la $t0, w
        la $t1, x
        la $t2, y
        la $t3, z
        li $t4, 0xaaaaaaaa
loop:   lb $t5, ($t4)   
        bqez
end:    
        li $v0, 10
        syscall

.data
w:  .word 0
x:  .word 0
y:  .word 0
z:  .word 0
```

Comment: Have you tried loading the address of w once, storing the data, and incrementing the address afterwards?

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea. Didn't really think about that. Thank you!